# What data structure to use for timeseries data logging in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, bigdata, database, nosql

I have 21 million rows (lines in csv files) that I want to import into MongoDB to report on.

The data comes a process on each PC's within our organisation - which create a row every 15 minutes showing who is logged on.

Columns are: date/time, PC Name, UserName, Idle time (if user logged on)

I need to be able to report from a PC POV (PC usage metrics) and a User POV (user dwell time and activity/movement).

Initially I just loaded the data using mongoimport. But this raw data structure is not easy to report on.  This could simply be my lack of knowledge of MongoDB.

I have been reading http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb which is a great article on schema design for time series data in mongodb.

This makes sense for reporting on PC usage - as I could pre-process the data and load it into Mongo as one document per PC/date combination, with an array of hourly buckets.

However I suspect this would make reporting from the user POV difficult.

I'm now thinking of create two collection - one for PC data and another for user data (one document per user/date combination etc).

I would like to know if I'm on the right track - or if anyone could suggest a better solution, of if indeed the original, raw data would suffice - and instead I just need to know how to query from both angles (some kind of map-reduce).

Thanks
Tim

Comment: To help make the discussion concrete, could you show us a sample row, a sample doc of how you are thinking of structuring things as timeseries data, and an example of the kinds of output you want to see (e.g. how do you calculate "dwell time"? Any proposed document structures for your second collection would be helpful to include as well.